# Update products when placing an order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-attribute, quote

I tried to change the **attribute value** once we click on **Place Order** button present in checkout page :

**config.xml**  :

```
<sales_convert_quote_to_order>
    <observers>
        <example_place_order>
            <class>Amasty_Example_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>PlaceOrder</method>
        </example_place_order>
    </observers>
</sales_convert_quote_to_order>
```

**app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Model - Observer.php**

```
public function PlaceOrder($observer)
{ 
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($product->getId()),
        array('cart_status' => 0),
        $storeId = 0
    );
}
```

**Result**

> Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object in line: `$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this ... it should set `cart_status` to `0` for all ordered products:

```
public function PlaceOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $productIds = array();

    foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        $productIds,
        array('cart_status' => 0),
        $storeId = 0
    );
}
```

Comment: now when i click on `place order`, i dont see any error and order placed successfully, but its not changing value of the attribute......

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your continous help and valuable time......

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public function PlaceOrder($observer) { 

     $product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getProduct();
      Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
         array($product->getId()),
         array('cart_status' => 0),
         $storeId = 0
      );
}
```

Comment: now it show error : `Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object in` in line `$product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getProduct();`