# Update Product attributes only if order successfull

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, event-observer

I tried to change the **attribute value** of Product's attribute [`cart_status`] once we click on **Place Order** button and **make the payment**.

Means Only if order is **successfull**. I guess this is correct event : `<sales_order_payment_capture>` as i saw [here](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/)

**config.xml**  :

```
<sales_order_payment_capture>
    <observers>
        <example_place_order>
            <class>Amasty_Example_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>PlaceOrder</method>
        </example_place_order>
    </observers>
</sales_order_payment_capture>
```

**app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Model - Observer.php**

```
public function PlaceOrder($observer)
{ 
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct(); 
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array(
        $product->getId()),
        array('cart_status' => 0),
        $storeId = 0
    );
}
```

**Result** :

**Fatal error** : Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in `array($product->getId()),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` observer

```
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    <observers>
        <update_product_attribute>
            <class>YourPackageName_YourModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>updateProductAttribute</method>
        </update_product_attribute>
    </observers>
</checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

Observer:

```
<?php
    public function updateProductAttribute($observer){
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach($items as $i){
                $product = $i->getProduct();
                $product->setCartStatus(0);
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as improvement for answer above ... for better performance please avoid calling `save`, `load` or `delete` inside a loop.

In this case you can just collect product IDs and use`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()` as written in your question.

```
public function updateProductAttribute($observer)
{
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        return;
    }

    $productIds = array();

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($items as $i) {
            $productIds[] = $i->getProduct()->getId();
        }
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        $productIds,
        array('cart_status' => 0),
        $storeId = 0
    );
}
```

---

Maybe to save you some time ...  you're dealing with a lot of events/observer at the moment, what is the prefered way instead of rewriting classes. So this may help you ...

1.) find available events (**just do it on test environment!**)

Open `app/Mage.php` and add one line to `dispatchEvent()` method

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Mage::log($name, null, $name . '.log', true);
    ...
}
```

To get the data from this event you can also do this here:

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    if ($name == 'event_you_want_to_log') {
        Mage::log(array($name, $data), null, $name . '.log', true);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, do the action you want to observe and comment `Mage::log` again.

2.) get data from observer

In this case you'll get something like this:

```
2017-06-15T07:34:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Varien_Event_Observer Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [event] => Varien_Event Object
                (
                    ...

                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [order_ids] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 15
                                )

                            [name] => checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
                        )
                    ...
                )

            [order_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15
                )
        )
    ...
)
```

You can access data with either `$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()` or `$observer->getOrderIds()`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to make things better, i updated your code, now i can able to place an order successfully, but attribute value is not changing.... when you get free time, please check once.....

Comment: Just was a typo - missing `)` ... please check again.

Comment: yes buddy , i tried that before , still i faced same...... we faced similar issue last time here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178802/update-products-when-placing-an-order/178811?noredirect=1#comment245444_178811

Comment: Another "typo" ... please compare code from your question ... one `array` to much ;)

Comment: my bad , sorry.....  worked now, yes i am using 3 events now in Observer , i am really going to try your 2nd part of answer to save time.... there is no option to accept 2 answers in the site , i really dont want to unaccept the other answer as i already accepted that....  but i really appreciate your help....

Comment: Its OK, other answer is correct ... was just to improve ;)